# NuxtJs SSR deployment on Cloudflare Workers

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, cloudflare-workers

I'm working on a Nuxt project and would like to deploy it on Cloudflare Workers with its SSR feature, not a static site. I could find a [solution](https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-a-static-nuxtjs-site-to-cloudflare-workers) for static site deployment below.

```
wrangler init --site
```

And in the wrangler.toml

```
account_id = "<account-id>"
name = "nuxt-cloudflare-workers"
type = "webpack"
route = ""
workers_dev = true
zone_id = ""

[site]
bucket = "dist"
entry-point = "workers-site"
```

And then

```
npm run generate

wrangler publish
```

But this simply deploys the Nuxt static site to the Cloudflare Workers. Is there anyone who knows how to deploy Nuxt SSR on Cloudflare workers?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a thread here about Nuxt SSR on Workers, but it's not clear if it's ready yet: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/vue-js-ssr-cloudflare-workers/218563

Answer (score 2):

This feature will be available with Nuxt Nitro (Nuxt3) but is not available as of right now.

So you cannot use Nuxt SSR on cloudflare workers as of **today**.

This event may be interesting to follow: https://twitter.com/danielcroe/status/1400115389854593029?s=19

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You can absolutely to SSR in Cloudflare Workers. Even on the free tier, which gives you 100,000 requests per day.

Comment: @kenton so far, Atinux told that until Nuxt3 is out, this is not doable yet. Not sure if you had any access to the beta but this is not doable as of **today** with Nuxt2.

Comment: Thanks @KentonVarda, do you mean that I can use Nuxt SSR mode on Cloudflare workers?

Comment: @kissu Yes, it does appear that Nuxt doesn't support Cloudflare Workers quite yet (coming in Nuxt3). However, that's not what your answer appears to say. Your answer says that SSR (in general) can't work on Cloudflare because it is "servereless". That's incorrect reasoning -- many SSR frameworks work fine on Cloudflare and on other Serverless providers. For example, Flareact is a version of Preact that works on Cloudflare Workers.

Comment: @kent Yeah, my answer is scoped to the Nuxt tag actually. Will edit it when on PC. Still not sure about the downvote since it is not doable. I did not get the serverless + SSR part before so I guess I will extrapolate a bit more.

Comment: @kissu Yes, my scope was to deploy the current version of Nuxt as SSR mode, not to see if Cloudflare workers support SSR. Your answer is what I was after. This is my first question on this platform and I really appreciate all your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not quite the same, but you can achieve Nuxt SSR with Vercel. Still achieving the serverless functionality for it.